# For loop in R for creating new data frames with respect to rows of a particular column

Tags: r, list, dataframe, for-loop

Hello I have created a forloop to split my data with respect to a certain row as so:

```
for(i in 1:(nrow(df)))

{

team_[[i]] <- df %>% filter(team == i)

}
```

R doesn't like this, as it says team_ not found. the code does run if I include a list as such

```
team_ <- list()

for(i in 1:(nrow(df)))

{

team_[[i]] <- df %>% filter(team == i)

}
```

This works... However, I am given a list with thousands of empty items and just a few that contain my filtered data sets.

is there a simpler way to create the data sets without this list function?

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simpler option is `split` from `base R` which would be faster than using `==` to subset in a loop

```
team_ <- split(df, df$team)
```

---

If we want to do some operations for each row, in `tidyverse`, it can be done with `rowwise`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    rowwise %>%
    ... step of operations ...
```

or with `group_by`

```
df %>%
   group_by(team) %>%
   ...
```

Comment: Wow... I cannot believe you have answered that with 1 line. Thank you so much.

Comment: How do we then extract the data frames from the list?

Comment: @T.Omalley you can use regular extraction methods i.e. `[[` - `team_[[1]]` or ` wiith the names `team_[["teamname1"]]` or with `$` `team_$teamname1`

Comment: I will be doing so, I have to wait a certain amount of time before I can accept it

Answer (score 2):

The methods akrun suggests are much better than a loop, but you should understand *why* this isn't working. Remember `for(i in 1:nrow(df))` will give you one list item for i = 1, i = 2, etc, right up until `i = nrow(df)`, which is several thousand by the sounds of thing. If you don't have any rows where `team` is 1, you will get an empty data frame as the first item, and the same will be true for every other value of `i` that isn't represented.

A loop like this would work:

```r
for(i in unique(df$team)) team_[[i]] <- df %>% filter(team == i)
```

But I would stick to a non-looping method as described by akrun.